# Adding scrollbars to QDockWidgets area

Tags: c++, qt

For my Qt application, I have used dock widgets, but enabling too many dockwidgets causes them to flow out of the screen at the bottom.
How do I add a scrollbar to the whole dockwidget area?

Here's an example:

[image]

Code of a dock widget :

```
QDockWidget *imageDock = new QDockWidget(i18n("Image"), this);
imageDock->setObjectName("ImageDock");
ImageChooserWidget *imageChooserWidget = new ImageChooserWidget(this);
imageDock->setWidget(imageChooserWidget);
addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea, imageDock);
m_dockWidgets.append(imageDock);
actionCollection()->addAction("show_image_dock", imageDock->toggleViewAction());
imageDock->setVisible(false);
connect(m_vocabularyView, SIGNAL(translationChanged(KEduVocExpression*, int)),
imageChooserWidget, SLOT(setTranslation(KEduVocExpression*, int)));
```

Also I have this before hand:

```
setCorner(Qt::TopLeftCorner, Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea);
setCorner(Qt::BottomLeftCorner, Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea);
setCorner(Qt::TopRightCorner, Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);
setCorner(Qt::BottomRightCorner, Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a `QScrollArea`, put it into the dock widget and put your contents into the scroll area. You may need to call `scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true)` to make it to resize your contents properly.

Comment: thnx, even though that wasn't exactly what I needed, but it'll work. Also, tabifyDockWidget() doesn't work for me? Any ideas?

Comment: This does not answer to the question. The question specifically asks for adding the *scrollbar to the whole dockwidget area* rather than to each specific `QDockWidget`.